# Unable to store data in firestore using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an instagram clone, It has a signup form which has four fields, Full Name, Username, Email and Password. I have created a state object named inputs which has four different properties that store the respective field's values.
I want the email and password to first get stored in the authentication section on firebase and store the full name and username in the firestore database but on submitting the form when the function named signup runs that is in a custom hook named 'useSignUpWithEmailAndPassword', it runs tills the point it is creating a new user in the authentication section on firebase, after which it is not throwing any error or creating a collection in firestore.

**Here is my SignUp.jsx file's code: -**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth, provider } from '../firebase';
import logo from "../assets/instagram-logo.png"
import FacebookLogo from "../assets/facebook-logos-white.svg"
import useSignUpWithEmailandPassword from '../hooks/useSignUpWithEmailAndPassword';

const SignUpPage = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        fullName: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
    })
    const { loading, error, signup } = useSignUpWithEmailandPassword()

    function handleLoginWithFacebook() {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            .then((result) => {
                navigate("/home")
                console.log(result)
                // The signed-in user info.
                props.setUser(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Handle Errors here.
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorCode, errorMessage)
            });
    }

    return (
        <main className='signup-page'>
            <section className='signin-form_section'>
                <div className='signup-form_top'>
                    <div>
                        <img src={logo} alt="Instagram Logo" className='instagram-logo' />
                        <p className='marketing-text'>Sign up to see photos and videos from your friends.</p>
                        <button className='facebook-login-btn-signup' onClick={handleLoginWithFacebook}>
                            <img src={FacebookLogo} width={"10px"} alt="Facebook Logo" className='facebook-logo-signup' />
                            Log in with Facebook
                        </button>
                        <p className='hr-lines'>OR</p>
                        <form>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                label="Full Name"
                                name='fullName'
                                autoComplete="given-name"
                                value={inputs.fullName}
                                onChange={(e) => setInputs({ ...inputs, fullName: e.target.value })}
                                required
                                placeholder="Full Name"
                            />
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                label="User Name"
                                name='username'
                                autoComplete="username"
                                value={inputs.username}
                                onChange={(e) => setInputs({ ...inputs, username: e.target.value })}
                                required
                                placeholder="Username"
                            />
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                name='email'
                                label="Email address"
                                value={inputs.email}
                                onChange={(e) => setInputs({ ...inputs, email: e.target.value })}
                                required
                                placeholder="Email address"
                            />
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                name='password'
                                label="Create password"
                                value={inputs.password}
                                onChange={(e) => setInputs({ ...inputs, password: e.target.value })}
                                required
                                placeholder="Password"
                            />
                            {error && (
                                    alert(error) 
                            )}

                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                onClick={() => signup(inputs)}
                                className='login-btn'
                            >
                                Sign up
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <p className='small-text contact-info-disclaimer'>
                        People who use our service may have uploaded 
                        your contact information to Instagram. 
                        Learn More
                    </p>
                    <p className="small-text termsconditions-text">
                    By signing up, you agree to our Terms , Privacy Policy and Cookies Policy.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p className="signin-form_bottom">
                    Have an account? {' '}
                    <NavLink 
                        to="/" 
                        style={{
                            color: "rgb(0, 149, 246)",
                            textDecoration: "none",
                            fontWeight: "500"
                        }}>
                        Log in
                    </NavLink>
                </p>
            </section>
        </main>
    )
}

export default SignUpPage
```

**useSignUpWithEmailAndPassword.js : -**

```
import { useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'
import { auth, firestore } from "../firebase"
import { doc, setDoc } from '@firebase/firestore';


const useSignUpWithEmailAndPassword = () => {
    const [
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
        loading,
        error,
    ] = useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
    alert(error);
    const signup = async (inputs) => {
        if (!inputs.email || !inputs.password || !inputs.username || !inputs.fullName) {
            console.log("Fill the")
            return
        }

        try {
            const newUser =  await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inputs.email, inputs.password);
            if (!newUser && error) {
                console.log(error)
                return;
            }
            if (newUser) {
                const userDoc = {
                    uid: newUser.user.uid,
                    email: inputs.email,
                    username: inputs.username,
                    fullName: inputs.fullName,
                    bio: "",
                    profilePicURl: "",
                    followers: [],
                    following: [],
                    posts: [],
                    createdAt: Date.now( )
                }
                await setDoc(doc(firestore, "users", newUser.user.uid), userDoc);
                localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(userDoc));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return console.log(error)
        }
    }
    return {loading , error, signup}
}

export default useSignUpWithEmailAndPassword
```

**Here is my firebase app initialisation: -**

````
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, FacebookAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyD8-C9Gb5lCY6Khvjz8zdoPY2tSnGTg0ZA",
  authDomain: "instagram-clone-15dff.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://instagram-clone-15dff-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "instagram-clone-15dff",
  storageBucket: "instagram-clone-15dff.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "362693890111",
  appId: "1:362693890111:web:c05ee2562639648adea88a"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);
export {app, auth, provider, firestore, storage};```

I I tried to console log the error but I didn't see any error.
````